# After removing all cache using git commands in android studio app, not showing other modules like "app" etc

Tags: android, git, caching

I have run below commands in android studio terminal on 'development' branch.

git rm -r --cached .

git add .

git commit -m "commitXYZ"

after that when I checkout to another branch and coming back to 'development' branch again, only gitignore files is showing not other modules like 'app' etc
Please see the attached screenshot.[image]